# Java security - MSCAPI provider: How to use without password popup?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, cryptoapi

I've managed to use [Sun's MSCAPI provider](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunMSCAPI) in my application. The problem I'm having now is that it always pops up a window, asking for a password, even though I've provided it in the code. This is a problem, because I need the cryptography functionality in a webservice.

Here's the code I have now:

```
String alias = "Alias to my PK";
char[] pass = "MyPassword".toCharArray();

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, pass);
Provider p =  ks.getProvider();

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA",p);
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass)

sig.initSign(key);
sig.update("Testing".getBytes());
sig.sign();
```

This is working great, but I get a popup asking for the password when the last line is run. How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MSCAPI provider does not support providing the password to CAPI:

> A compatibility mode is supported for applications that assume a password must be supplied. It permits (but ignores) a non-null password.  The mode is enabled by default. [(1)](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Platform/windows/sun/security/mscapi/KeyStore.java.htm)

To set the password through CAPI, you must call [CryptSetKeyParam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380272(VS.85).aspx) with the undocumented KP_KEYEXCHANGE_PIN or KP_SIGNATURE_PIN and hope your underlying hardware token provider supports it. (They are not completely undocumented - the documentation for Windows CE and Windows Mobile mention them [(2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa923647.aspx) and they are included in the header files).

Comment: I know this is a little old, but i need the exact same thing. Do you have an example of setting this to avoid the pin popup?

Comment: I filled a ticket to allow the password to be provided programmatically to the SunMSCAPI KeyStore, https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8232240

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Windows is popping up the pop up.

Import your key again using the Certificate Import Wizard, but make sure that you don't check the following option on the "Password" screen.

> [_] Enable strong private key protection. You will be prompted every time the private key is used by an application if you enable this option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't re-import the certificate because it's not a file but a hardware token that I'm using.

Comment: I have empty password in Java code. When I insert token to USB for first time and run Java application, popup window from token middleware is displayed and private key is accesible. But when I run application second and more times, application freezes. I must remove and insert token again.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved this problem setting the provider as follow:

`signeData = gen.generate(content, ks.getProvider());`

Where

`ks` is a `KeyStore` and

`gen`is a `CMSSignedDataGenerator`