# Using Microsoft Smart Card Minidriver in JAVA

Tags: java, smartcard

I have a custom smart card with PKI middleware (dll library) written by specification available at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487500.aspx

Is there a java wrapper for microsoft sc minidriver that I can use to access the card functions, or I would have to write my own JNI methods?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'll put as comment since it's not an actual answer: you can try the [smartcardio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html) package (pure Java) or use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) to access the dll (instead of JNI).

Comment: Yes I am currently trying to create a JNA wrapper, and I have some difficulties along the way.. Smartcardio provides ability to select a card form a terminal and execute APDU commands, but in this case I want to use dll to do that for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minidriver works below a layer that is meant to be accessed by external applications (it is a plugin for the Windows system, generally speaking). What you want is access to CryptoAPI layer (from where the minidriver functionality is exposed if the card is inserted) and SunMSCAPI should provide the possibility. Have a look at [Signing documents with SunMSCAPI and suppressing the "Enter PIN" dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496565/signing-documents-with-sunmscapi-and-suppressing-the-enter-pin-dialog) for example

Comment: Using SunMSCAPI I am able to get certificates from my Windows keystore, and thats as far as I can get. Maybe CryptoAPI is not working correcty with my driver? I have 64bit windows 7, but driver is 32bit, if that matters...

Comment: Yes. Your on-card certificates will end up in Windows keystores as well, so the problem is nonfunctioning minidriver.

Comment: Thank you, I will contact my vendor and see if I can get another minidriver