# Perform signature with a password protected MS store key using SecureBlackBox Java

Tags: java

Is there an equivalent for the following JCE `SunMSCAPI` based code **for a password protected MS store key** using SecureBlackBox Java API?.

```
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
keyStore.load(null);
String firstAlias = keyStore.aliases().nextElement();
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(firstAlias, null);
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(new byte[]{0x01, 0x02}); // TBS
byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(signatureBytes));
```

Comment: As suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6496565/signing-documents-with-sunmscapi-and-suppressing-the-enter-pin-dialog/6496905?noredirect=1#comment103329584_6496905, I submitted a ticket (https://sbb.eldos.com/helpdesk/ticket_edit.php?ID=35201) to the company and I will try to share their answer when I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you totally - well, unless the underlying cryptographic provider is subject to some very non-standard peculiarities - can do that with SecureBlackbox. You can pass both 'key exchange' and 'signature' pins to the key provider.

We offer a no obligation evaluation package on the web site - please feel free to try it and see if it works with your keys. We can talk you through the process in more detail in the support channels.

Thanks,

Ken