# Accessing private key of hardware token in Java

Tags: java, certificate, keystore

I'm trying to access the private key of my certificate using the keystore.

Here's my code :

```
package test.java.com;

import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        KeyStore ks;
        try {
            ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");

            ks.load(null, null);
            Enumeration<String> en = ks.aliases();
            while (en.hasMoreElements()) {
                String aliasKey = (String) en.nextElement();
                Certificate c = ks.getCertificate(aliasKey);
                Key key = ks.getKey(aliasKey, "1753".toCharArray()); // Here I try to access the private key of my hardware certificate
                byte[] bt = key.getEncoded();

                if(bt != null) {
                    System.out.println("private key correctly accessed");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Can't access private key");
                }

                System.out.println("---> alias : " + aliasKey);
                if (ks.isKeyEntry(aliasKey)) {
                    Certificate[] chain = ks.getCertificateChain(aliasKey);
                    System.out.println("---> chain length: " + chain.length);
                    X509Certificate Cert = null;
                    for (Certificate cert : chain) {
                        System.out.println(cert);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

But when I try to get the private key (in order to sign data with it), the private key is null.

Am I doing it wrong ? How to sign data with that certificate using its private key ?

Note : I must use the keystore (I can't use the DLL of the hardware token driver because I could have many differents drivers coming to the server).

Comment: I have empty password in Java code.
When I insert token to USB for first time and run Java application, popup window from token middleware is displayed and private key is accesible.
But when I run application second and more times, application freezes.
I must remove and insert token again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer from this post : [Java security - MSCAPI provider: How to use without password popup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495392/java-security-mscapi-provider-how-to-use-without-password-popup)

```
String alias = "Alias to my PK";
char[] pass = "MyPassword".toCharArray();

KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY");
ks.load(null, pass);
Provider p =  ks.getProvider();

Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA",p);
PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, pass)

sig.initSign(key);
sig.update("Testing".getBytes());
sig.sign();
```

Answer (score 0):

The private key is null unless it's a KeyEntry. You tried to get the private key out of a CertificateEntry, so you got an NPE. Just test the type of entry before you try for the private key: or, just test it for null, and if so, keep enumerating.