# How to load Windows-MY keystore with pin/password in Java?

Tags: java, applet, x509certificate, keystore, digital-certificate

I am developing java applet which should be able to read certificates from  Windows-MY instance. This is the part that I am able to do and is working fine. My problem is when I enter PIN code (provided via edit text control), Windows certificate manager after that asks me again for the same PIN code.

So, I have few question and will be very thankful if you are able to help me.

1. What am I doing wrong in my code, why it is not using my PIN provided via `EditText` control? How to accomplish that?
2. If that is not possible, please if you can tell me, do PKCS#12 Digital Certificates are behaving in the same way like PKCS#11 Smart Card Certificates? To be precise, do they asking for PIN in the same manner like PKCS#11? If it so, I should be able to remove my field for PIN and leave Windows to do that part of the job.

Here is part of the code used in my applet:

```
keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");
keystore.load(null,_PIN);

String aliass = (String) aliasses.nextElement();
X509Certificate oPublicCertificate = (X509Certificate) keystore.getCertificate(alias);
PrivateKey oPrivateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias,null);
if(oPrivateKey == null) continue;
if(aliass != alias) continue;

System.out.println("Sign with alias:"+aliass);
System.out.println("gettype:"+oPublicCertificate.getType());
System.out.println("serial:"+oPublicCertificate.getSerialNumber());
System.out.println("Public Key:"+oPublicCertificate.getPublicKey());
 _PK = Base64Utils.base64Encode(oPublicCertificate.getPublicKey().getEncoded());
System.out.println("Public Key:"+_PK);

Provider p = keystore.getProvider();
// data to sign
byte[] data ="Data for signing".getBytes();
// Signing the data
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
sig.initSign(oPrivateKey);

sig.update(data);

byte[] signature = sig.sign();  //<--- Here asks for PIN second time.

System.out.println("Signature.sign():" + signature);

Signature verifier = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", p);
verifier.initVerify(oPublicCertificate);
verifier.update(data);
boolean isValidSignature = verifier.verify(signature);
System.out.println("the verification result "+ isValidSignature);
```

I *am* open for different approaches to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a callback handler 
please check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/callback/CallbackHandler.html)

as this example copied from the mentioned reference which override the callbacks handling

```
public void handle(Callback[] callbacks)
 throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {

   for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
      if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback) {

          // prompt the user for sensitive information
          PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
          System.err.print(pc.getPrompt());
          System.err.flush();
          pc.setPassword(readPassword(System.in));

      } 
   }
 }
```

then you can use your callback

```
CallbackHandler callBackHandler = new yourImplementedHandler();
KeyStore.ProtectionParameter protection = new KeyStore.CallbackHandlerProtection(callBackHandler);
Provider provider = Security.getProvider("SunMSCAPI");
KeyStore.Builder keystoreBuilder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("Windows-MY",
                                                                provider, 
                                                                protection);
KeyStore keystore = keystoreBuilder.getKeyStore();
```

I hope this could help.

Comment: Did you test your provided solution?. I think you didn't because SunMSCAPI KeyStore implementation completely ignores the password provided as indicated in http://stackoverflow.com/a/495793/320594.